# Prove that, for any sentence A of the predicate calculus with identity, at least one of spectrum(A) and spectrum(¬ A) is cofinite

Tags: logic, model-theory, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I got the following exercise:

> Prove that, for any sentence A of the predicate calculus with
>   identity, at least one of spectrum(A) and spectrum(¬ A) is cofinite.

I already tried to prove this theorem by a proof by contradiction. So suppose spectrum(A) and spectrum(¬ A) are both not cofinite. Then clearly, spectrum(A) and spectrum(¬ A) are infinite. Thus A and ¬ A have both infinite models. But I don't no how to go on ...

Could you please help me, dear stackexchange?

We got the hint that the following lemma is helpful: For any firstorder sentence s, if spectrum(s) is infinite, then s has an infinite model.

Comment: What is meant by spectrum ? Its not standard in model theory.

Comment: It is standard in finite model theory ;-D The spectrum of a first order sentence s is defined to be the set of all cardinalities of finite models of s.

Comment: Nobody of you knows an answer? Not even Asaf Karagila or Noah Schweber?

Comment: You are assuming that there are no predicates ?

Comment: I dont know. But if we are assuming that our language has no predicate symbols, no function symbols and no constant symbols, then the proof of our theorem is easy.

Comment: Ok, well there you go, its false with predicates.

Comment: That is funny. If an exercise says that I shall proof theorem A, I usually don't question the truth of A. ;-D

Comment: @ReneSchipperus: You can post your comment together with an explanation as an answer to my question.

Comment: For instance, on certain structures there are formulas that are true iff the structure is of even size (when it is finite). Obviously, both its spectrum and the spectrum of its negation are then infinite.

Comment: @Graffitics: I think this is not a counterexample, since a spectrum does not necessarily have to be not cofinite if it is infinite.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus: Could you give a counterexample? That is, can you give me a first-order sentence A such that both spectrum(A) and spectrum(not A) are not cofinite?

Comment: I read " at least one of spectrum(A) and spectrum(¬ A) is cofinite", is the question something else?

Comment: @zewgi This is a good question, but it's a bit much to complain about not getting an answer after only a couple hours. (Also, are you the same person who has been posting questions about spectra? If so, why the username change?)

Comment: @ReneSchipperus I think that's incorrect - see my answer below. Can you sketch a counterexample?

Comment: @Noah: Yes, I am that stupid guy who asked these questions :-D I ask my questions with a guest account, and deleting the cookies of my browser automatically logs me out, that is why I always have a new account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the comments thread, the result is **true**. Although it can be a bit tricky to see.

To start with, let's consider an obvious possible line of attack for producing a counterexample: restricting to finite structures with some property. E.g., there *is* a sentence $\varphi$ whose spectrum is infinite but not cofinite, *in the context of groups*: namely $\varphi=$"There is an element of order $2$." However, if we try to turn this into an actual counterexample, we would look at either $\varphi_1=$"If the structure is a group, it has an element of order $2$" or $\varphi_2=$"The structure is a group and has an element of order $2$." The spectrum of $\varphi_1$ is cofinite - the non-groups - and the spectrum of $\neg \varphi_2$ is cofinite - again, the non-groups. So restricting to the groups context breaks everything.

So here's the hint: fix a first-order sentence $\varphi$ in some language. Say the *prespectrum* of $\varphi$, $pres(\varphi)$, is the complement of the spectrum of $\neg\varphi$. Intuitively, $n\in pres(\varphi)$ if, no matter how I interpret the symbols in $\varphi$ on a set of size $n$, I get a model of $\varphi$. Then:

- If $\varphi$ and $\neg\varphi$ each have co-infinite spectra, then $pres(\varphi)$ and $pres(\neg\varphi)$ are each infinite.
- Can you see how to convert a sentence $\psi$ with some symbols into a sentence in the empty language $\psi'$, such that the spectrum of $\psi'$ contains $pres(\psi)$ and has empty intersection with $pres(\neg\psi)$? (HINT: Think about some things that e.g. a unary relation could be . . .) If you can do this, you'll have reduced the problem to the empty language case.

Comment: A technical note: this is noticeably easier if the language only contains **relation** symbols (no constants or functions), in which case the translation from $\psi$ to $\psi'$ (really, *a* translation - there are many possible ones which work) is very easy. With constants and function symbols, it's still straightforward, just slightly messier.

Comment: Thanks, your anwer might be helpful.

Comment: Assuming both $\mathrm{Spectrum}(A)$ and $\mathrm{Spectrum}(\neg A)$ are both co-infinite, then by the hint (essentially Löwenheim/Skolem Th.) both $A$ and $\neg A$ have each an infinite model. Doesn't this lead to a contradiction? (And I am assuming the language has no operations or constants. Only potentially predicates, and always including the identity predicate)

Comment: @John "Doesn't this lead to a contradiction?" Definitely not. For example, consider the language with a single unary predicate symbol $U$, and the sentence $A\equiv$ "$\exists x(\neg U(x))$." Clearly both $A$ and $\neg A$ have infinite models; there's no contradiction, though, since these infinite models aren't isomorphic.

Comment: @John If the language is just the language of $=$, then yes, you're correct. But no such assumption is made in my answer, or in the original post itself as far as I can tell.

Comment: @John Use Lowenheim-Skolem. If $A,B$ are infinite structures in the empty language, by LS we get *countable $A',B'$ in the empty language with $A\equiv A'$ and $B\equiv B'$. But this means $$A\equiv A'\cong B'\equiv B,$$ so $A\equiv B$, i.e. any two infinite structures in the empty language are elementarily equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Ok well I just looked it up. Take the theory that says there are at least $n$ elements for each $n$, and in which all constants are equal and all relations are satisfied by all tuples. There is essentially only one model of this theory and if that model satisfies $\sigma$ then some finite set of the axioms will imply $\sigma$ and so $\sigma$ has cofinite spectrum.