# Is there a first-order sentence $A$ such that the set of finite sizes of structures satisfying $A$ is not cofinite, and same for $\neg A$?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Let $\mathscr L$ be a first-order language with equality and a single two-place predicate $P$.  Is there a sentence $A$ in this language such that $\{n:M\vDash A \text{ with } |M| = n\}$ is not cofinite (i.e. its complement in $\mathbb N$ is not finite) and also $\{n:M\vDash \neg A \text{ and } |M|=n\}$ is not cofinite?

A natural attempt would be to try to construct a sentence $A$ which is satisfied by precisely those structures with a domain of size a (finite) even number.  But if it were possible to do that, you'd think you could use a solution to build a sentence which is satisfied precisely by the finite domain structures--which I believe is impossible.  This all makes me think that such a sentence is impossible.  But now I'm wondering how I could prove this.

I'm not even sure where to start.  I've tried thinking along the lines "Suppose such a sentence exists" and getting a contradiction, but I haven't even been able to come up with a "step 2".

---

I may (or may not) have made some amount of progress on this:

I know that, using compactness, it is possible to prove that a formula with one free variable cannot define a set that is neither finite nor cofinite. So suppose that a sentence $S$ exists such that the conditions described above hold, and form the formula $T(x)=S\land x=x$. It feels like there should be a way to say that this formula defines, in some structure, a set that is neither finite nor cofinite. Intuitively I feel like I should "union" all the structures which satisfy $S$. But that probably doesn't exactly work.

Comment: @EricWofsey Right, I think I've fixed it.

Comment: How about: $\forall x \exists ! y (y\ne x \land P(x,y))$

Comment: @Karl Wouldn't that be satisfied by, say, a structure of $n$ elements that form a "cycle"?   Then $\{n : M\vDash A \text{ with } |M|=n\} = \mathbb N$ and so it's cofinite, therefore isn't an example?

Comment: Ah, yeah, I meant to also require that $P$ is a symmetric relation so that it "pairs up" the elements. That is: $(\forall x\forall y(P(x,y)\iff P(y,x)))\land\forall x \exists ! y (y\ne x \land P(x,y)).$

Comment: @Karl Right, so I had thought of something similar, but it seems to me that the negation of this is a wide-open space.  The negation just says "Things do not necessarily pair up perfectly," and therefore there are all kinds of structures satisfying this negation, no?

Comment: Oh, good point. I see the difficulty now.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm still curious. The observation that it's hard to come up with a sentence that's neither "too easy to satisfy" nor "too easy to fail to satisfy" seems related to zero-one laws, e.g. as discussed [here](https://jeremykun.com/2015/02/09/zero-one-laws-for-random-graphs/).

Comment: @Karl Nope, never figured it out.  Just can't think of a next move to make for the proof.

Comment: @Karl I may have made some amount of progress.  I know that, using compactness, it is possible to prove that a formula with one free variable cannot define a set that is neither finite nor cofinite.  So suppose that a sentence $S$ exists such that the conditions described above hold, and form the formula $T(x) = S \land x=x$.  It feels like there should be a way to say that this formula defines, in some structure, a set that is neither finite nor cofinite.  Intuitively I feel like I should "union" all the structures which satisfy $S$.  But that probably doesn't exactly work.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Consider structures where the relation $P$ is "trivial" in some sense, so that it doesn't contribute anything interesting to what formulas you can make.

More details are hidden below.

> You can equip any set $M$ with the binary relation $P$ that is always true.  For such structures, we may as well be working in the language with only equality, since $P$ will always evaluate to $\top$.  But now if $A$ is a sentence in the first-order language with only equality, the set of finite cardinalities of its models are either finite or cofinite.  So, either $A$ or $\neg A$ has models of cofinitely many finite cardinalities.

Comment: Hm.  I can't use the fact that an FOL sentence's set of finite cardinalities of its models are either finite or cofinite--it sounds like a result that is a little much for me to prove in service of the problem.  So I may need to find another way.  Thanks though!

Comment: @Addem Did you figure it out? Check https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4486300/proving-that-for-any-first-order-sentence-a-at-least-one-of-mathrmspa-o and also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1774333/prove-that-for-any-sentence-a-of-the-predicate-calculus-with-identity-at-least/1774582?noredirect=1#comment9407593_1774582

Comment: @Addem I will also add that for the empty language (i.e. with only =) the fact that at least one of $\mathrm{Spectrum}(A)$ or $\mathrm{Spectrum}(\neg A)$ is cofinite follows from the fact that in the empty language any two infinite structures are elementary equivalent (easy consequence of Lowenheim/Skolem's Theorem - LS) Then, if say $\mathrm{Spectrum}(A)$ is co-infinite, then again by LS $\neg A$ has an infinite model, and thus $A$ cannot have an infinite model. Hence, again by LS it cannot have models of arbitrarily large finite cardinality and thus $\mathrm{Spectrum}(\neg A)$ is cofinite.

Comment: @John I didn’t figure it out, but I really just was doing this for an assignment.  It seems like a question I am not actually interested in understanding, so it remains unsolved to me.