# For any first order sentence $A$ at least one of $\mathrm{Sp}(A)$ or $\mathrm{Sp}(\neg A)$ is cofinite

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, model-theory

My approach is different, but [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1774333/prove-that-for-any-sentence-a-of-the-predicate-calculus-with-identity-at-least/1774582?noredirect=1#comment9407593_1774582) includes an answer. Also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4118064/is-there-a-first-order-sentence-a-such-that-the-set-of-finite-sizes-of-structu) MSE question is related. I assume the first order language $\mathcal{L}$ to have constant symbols, predicate symbols (including the identity predicate $=$) and operation symbols. The result is true, as you can read in the first link above. I have a question regarding the viability of my approach:

Let $A$ be an $\mathcal{L}$-sentence. The spectrum of $A$ is the set $\mathrm{Sp}(A)=\{m\geq 1:\mbox{there is $M\vDash A$ with $|U_{M}|=m$}\}$, where $M$ denotes an $L$-structure and $U_{M}$ denotes its domain.

Attempt at a proof (First I assume $\mathcal{L}$ has no operation symbols): Let $S$ be the set of sentences:

1. $\alpha_{m}:=\exists x_{1}\ldots\exists x_{m}\,\neg((x_{1}=x_{2})\vee(x_{1}=x_{3})\vee\ldots\vee(x_{m-1}=x_{m}))$, for all $m\geq 1$.
2. $\forall \bar{x}\,P\bar{x}$, for all predicates $P\in\mathcal{L}$ (where $\bar{x}$ denotes a $k$-tuple according to the $k$-arity of the predicate $P$).
3. $(a=b)$, for all constants $a,b\in\mathcal{L}$.

First, the set $S$ is satisfiable. One may take simply a structure $M$ having domain $\mathbb{N}$, all constants interpreted as $0$ and each $k$-ary predicates interpreted as the cartesian product of $k$ copies of $\mathbb{N}$.

Now, I would like the set $S$ to be *complete* in the sense that given an $\mathcal{L}$-sentence $A$, either $S\vDash A$ or $S\vDash\neg A$. Why? because if $S$ is complete, say $S\vDash A$, by the Compactness Theorem there is a finite set $S_{0}\subseteq S$ such that $S_{0}\vDash A$. Then, there is a positive integer $n_{0}$ larger than any $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\alpha_{m}$ is in $S_{0}$. But this means $S_{0}$ and hence $A$ is satisfiable in domains of cardinality $n$ for each $n\ge 0$, i.e. $\mathrm{Sp}(A)$ is cofinite (similarly, we obtain $\mathrm{Sp}(\neg A)$ is cofinite if $S\vDash \neg A$).

Hence, my question is: **Is the set $S$ complete in the sense described above?** It would be enough to show that any two structures satisfying $S$ are elementary equivalent. But I don't see how to do this.

Remark on a language with operations symbols: First, perform the well-known passage from a language with operations to an operation-free one. Then, for each new predicate $F$ corresponding to a $k$-ary operation $f$, in 2. above instead of the sentence
$$\forall x_{1}\ldots\forall x_{k}\,\forall y\,Fx_{1}\ldots x_{n}y,$$
add to $S$ the sentence
$$\forall x_{1}\ldots\forall x_{k}\,\exists y\,(Fx_{1}\ldots x_{k}y\wedge \forall z\,(Fx_{1}\ldots x_{k}z\Rightarrow (y=z))),$$
or equivalently, the sentence $\forall x_{1}\ldots\forall x_{k}\,\exists y\,\forall z\,(Fx_{1}\ldots x_{n}z\Leftrightarrow (y=z))$.
The argument above applies to this modified set $S$ without modifications.

---

EDIT: I can prove the equivalent statement that for any $L$-sentence $A$, either $S\vDash A$ or $S\vDash\neg A$ is by using induction on the degree of the sentence. Does anyone know another way?

Comment: Would it be enough to show that any two *countable* structures satisfying $S$ are elementarily equivalent?

Comment: @bof I think not if the language is uncountable, in which case $S$ would be uncountable as well.

Comment: Can't we assume that the only nonlogical symbols in the language are those occurring in the sentence $A$?

Comment: @bof How would that prove that given an any language and any sentence $A$ in that language at least one of $\mathrm{Sp}(A)$ or $\mathrm{Sp}(\neg A)$ is cofinite?

Comment: So the spectrum of $A$ depends not only on the sentence $A$ but also on the language? The same sentence can have different spectra in different languages? Forgive my ignorance, I only took one undergraduate class in Symbolic Logic, and that was in a previous century.

Comment: What if you take the language of groups $\mathcal L = \{+,0\}$ and consider the sentence saying that there is an element of order $2$. Then a finite group satisfying this must be even, and all even groups contain an element of order $2$, so the spectrum of its negation is exactly all odd numbers.

Comment: @bof No, we are trying to show that for any sentence $A$ in a first order language $\mathcal{L}$ either the spectrum of $A$ or the spectrum of $\neg A$ is cofinite. $A$ is an arbitrary sentence in the language, and we know nothing explicit about it.

Comment: @SimoneRamello The spectrum of your sentence is cofinite -the non-groups.

Comment: @John you can turn the sentence into "I'm a group" + "I have an element of order 2".

Comment: If $A$ is a sentence in an uncountable language $\mathrm L$ then there is a countable sublanguage $\mathrm L_0\subset\mathrm L$ containg all the symbols of $A$, so that $A$ is also a sentence in $L_0$. Isn't the spectrum of $A$ the same, whether $A$ is considered a sentence in the language $L_0$ or the original language $L$?

Comment: @bof Yes, but again, we are trying to prove the result for any $L$-sentence.

Comment: @SimoneRamello Ok, to be clear, your sentence "I am a group and I have an element of order 2" has its negation having cofinite spectrum. That is, your latest sentence has cofinite spectrum. You may also consider "If I am a group then I have an element of order 2" which also has cofinite spectrum. Don't bother looking for a counterexample. The result is true. See the first link on the first paragraph. I am just trying to prove it differently.

Comment: If any $\mathrm L$-sentence $A$ is also an $\mathrm L_0$-sentence for some countable language $\mathrm L_0$, why isn't it enough to prove it for sentences in a countable language? What am I missing?

Comment: @bof Again, because your $L_0$ (which you may say it is finite, not just countable) is dependent on $A$, and the result we seek is for ANY $L$-sentence $A$.

Comment: I must be missing something very stupid and obvious, because I don't see why "$\mathrm L_0$ is dependent on $A$" is a problem. What's wrong with saying: Let $\mathrm L$ be any first-order language and let $A$ be any $\mathrm L$-sentence; I have to show that either $\operatorname{Sp}(A)$ or $\operatorname{Sp}(\neg A)$ is cofinite. There is a countable language $\mathrm L_A$ such that $A$ is an $\mathrm L_A$-sentence. But we've already proved the result for sentences in a countable language. Therefore, either  $\operatorname{Sp}(A)$ or $\operatorname{Sp}(\neg A)$ is cofinite, Q.E.D.?

Comment: @bof Because you are making your proof depend on $A$, and it would not work for a $B$ whose symbols are different from those of $A$. Hence you are not proving the resukt for ANY $L$-sentence.

Comment: Doesn't the rule of Universal Generalization apply here? If I can prove the result for $A$, assuming only that $A$ is a sentence in $\mathrm L$, can't I infer that it holds for all sentences in $\mathrm L$? Then what about a proof by contradiction? If there is a counterexample, then there is some sentence $A$ in some language $\mathrm L$ such that neither $A$ nor $\neg A$ has a cofinite spectrum. But then $A$ is also a counterexample in the countable language $\mathrm L_A$, which is impossible.

Comment: @bof Universal generalization applies when your proof does not depend on the sentence $A$. As for your contradiction argument, it assumes what you're trying to prove.

Comment: @John bof is correct. You can assume that the language is finite.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Oh, good. Please, elaborate.

Comment: @John If $L'$ is a language containing $L$, then any $L$-structure can be expanded to an $L'$-structure (e.g. interpret all new function symbols as projection onto the first coordinate and all new relation symbols as $\emptyset$). Now suppose $\varphi$ is an $L$-sentence. Since expansion doesn't change the size of the model, the spectrum of $\varphi$ as an $L$-sentence is the same as the spectrum of $\varphi$ as an $L'$-sentence (even though there are more $L'$-structures than $L$-structures of a given finite size). Crucially, whether $\mathcal{M}\models\varphi$ depends only on the $L$-reduct.

Comment: @NoahSchweber @ bof I stand corrected, and thanks to your comment I see a finer point of the concepts involved that I did not see before. Thank you. Is there anything wrong with my argument answering the original question? As far as I can tell, it applies even if we assume the language to be finite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $S$ is indeed complete. Here is an easy argument for showing this:

**Lemma:** Let $T$ be any first-order $L$-theory with only infinite models, and suppose $T$ is $\kappa$-categorical for some cardinal $\kappa\geqslant\max\{\aleph_0, |L|\}$. (This means that any two models of $T$ of size $\kappa$ are isomorphic.) Then $T$ is complete.

**Proof:** Suppose $T$ is not complete; then there is a sentence $\phi$ such that $T\not\vdash \phi$ and $T\not\vdash\neg\phi$. By the completeness theorem, there are thus $L$-structures $M$ and $M'$, each a model of $T$, such that $M\models\phi$ and $M\models\neg\phi$. By the hypothesis on $T$, $M$ and $M'$ are infinite. Thus, by the Lowenheim-Skolem theorem (in particular the "upwards" version if $|M|$, resp $|M'|$, is smaller than $\kappa$ and the "downwards" version if $|M|$, resp $|M'|$, is greater than $\kappa)$, we can find $L$-structures $N$ and $N'$ of size $\kappa$ that are elementarily equivalent to $M$ and $M'$. But this means $N\models T\cup\{\phi\}$ and $N'\models T\cup\{\neg\phi\}$; since isomorphic structures are elementarily equivalent, this contradicts that $T$ is $\kappa$-categorical. $\blacksquare$

[Note that we really do need both the assumption on $\kappa$ and the assumption that $T$ has only infinite models here. In the first case, let $T$ be your favorite incomplete theory with infinite models, and then let $(c_i)_{i\in\mathbb{R}}$ be a family of fresh constant symbols. Then $T\cup\{c_i\neq c_j:i\neq j\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is still incomplete, but it is $\aleph_0$-categorical since it has no countable models! In the second case, let $\phi$ be any countably categorical sentence with an infinite model (eg the conjunction of the theory of dense linear orders without endpoints), and let $\psi$ be a sentence in the same language with two non-isomorphic models of size $n$ for some $n\in\omega$. Then the theory $\{\exists^{=n}x(x=x)\to\psi\}\cup\{\exists^{> n}x(x=x)\to\phi\}$ is still countably categorical but is not complete.]

Okay, now note that your theory $S$ has only infinite models. Thus by the lemma we need only show that your theory $S$ is categorical in some sufficiently large cardinal $\kappa$. In fact, $S$ is categorical in *any* cardinal; indeed, if $M$ and $M'$ are models of $S$ with the same cardinality, let $f:M\to M'$ be any bijection such that $f(c^M)=c^{M'}$ for each constant symbol $c$ in the language. (This makes sense since $c^M$ is fixed as $c$ varies, by definition of $S$.) You can check that $f$ is a bijective $L$-embedding, hence an isomorphism, so we are done.

Comment: Very nice! (+1) I have not learned about the concept of $\kappa$-categorical yet, so this is great.

Comment: @John my pleasure, happy it helped! :) it looks like you've been working a lot on finite model theory (?), in which (to my knowledge) categoricity does not play such a central role, but in infinite model theory there are some wonderful theorems on categoricity! the most striking and famous is [Morley's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_theory), which launched a great deal of new directions for the subject

Comment: What happens is that I am a beginner and only started learning logic in April. Hence, I stumble and make many silly mistakes, and I know little :)

Comment: @John well it looks like you are making great progress! :D

Comment: Thank you! It is a fascinating subject. Is there a particular textbook that you have particularly enjoyed learning from? I am using Smullyan's First Order Logic and David Marker's Model Theory: An Introduction.

Comment: @John Marker's book is absolutely fantastic and was my own first introduction to the subject! unfortunately I haven't read any of Smullyan's so I can't comment, but I have heard good things. for a "second course" that gets into some more modern notions, I would also recommend Tent and Ziegler, but only after you've gotten through at least the first half of Marker. from that point on there are many directions you could go! :)

Answer (score 1):

Atticus Stonestrom's answer suggested to me a way to show directly that any two structures satisfying $S$ are elementary equivalent. Thus, proving that $S$ is complete.

First, notice that $S$ is not satisfiable in any finite domain. That is, all the models of $S$ are infinite.

Next, as Atticus shows in his answer, any two structures of the same cardinality satisfying $S$ are isomorphic. But then, if $M$ and $M$ are structures satisfying $S$, both must be infinite, and by the Löwenheim-Skolem Theorem there are structures $N$ and $N'$ satisfying $S$, both having the same cardinality, and such that $M\equiv N$ and $M'\equiv N'$. But then $N\cong N'$ imples $M\equiv M'$, as desired.

Finally, it is not difficult to show that a (consistent, which our $S$ is) set of sentences in some first order language is complete if and only if any two models of the set are elementary equivalent.